# Difficulty including wordpress shortlink in am embedded (iframe) tweet button

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, twitter, tweets

I am trying to programmatically include a tweet button, in an iframe, on a page. I want this to tweet the wordpress shortlink of a specific post.

I am using PHP to insert into my wordpress database the following HTML iframe code to include the weet button.  The code looks like this

```
'<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  
src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html
?count=horizonatal?url=http://www.mywebsite.com?p= '
 . $post_id . '"></iframe>'
```

As you can see I am concatenating the $post_id, which is in the PHP code, with the rest of the wordpress shortlink "http://www.mywebsite.com?p=".  The problem appears to be that the twitter widget interprets the '?' in my url attribute as a query for itself -- as opposed to a query for my wordpress site - and what happens is I can only get http://www.mywebsite.com tweeted.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You need use urlencode:

```
'<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  
src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html
?count=horizonatal?url='.urlencode('http://www.mywebsite.com?p='.$post_id)
 .'"></iframe>'
```

Reading: http://www.php.net/urlencode